# OCaml resetting int ref values after loop

Tags: int, ocaml, immutability, ref

I currently have a nested for loop, after checking for values it increments each ref int within the function, What I am trying to do is have the ref int reset to 0 after each iteration of the inner for loop, but everything i've done has given me a syntax error and was wondering if I could get some help.

```
for i = 0 to striL -1 do 
    for j = !tempH to !tempT do
        countChar demoStri.[!tempH];
        if (!countA = !countC) && (!countC = !countG) && (!countG = !countT) then subStricount := !subStricount +1
    done
    let !countA = 0
    let !countC = 0
done
```

This is what I currently have and the countChar is a function that simply checks the string for certain char and increments each 'count' value. and is also what i am trying to reset to 0.

Answer (score 1):

To set the references to 0:

```
. . .
done;
countA := 0;
countC := 0
```

Note the uses of `;`. You can't simply write one expression after another, you need to separate them with `;`. (In fact, two adjacent expressions without a separator represent a function call.)